# JSP: Using the same Java object across pages

Tags: jsp

I have 2 jsp pages, index.jsp and viewer.jsp. viewer.jsp is inside an IFRAME in index.jsp.

index.jsp needs to grab a list of domain names from a Java object `foo` and provide a drop down menu for the user. After the user picks one and submits it, viewer.jsp needs to read this domain name and use `foo` to extract all the the data it needs to display.

How do I access `foo` across both pages? Is there a better way to construct this functionality?

I haven't done JSP before (or web programming for that matter), so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either put it in session scope, or replace the poor `iframe` approach by server side includes using `jsp:include` so that you can end up putting it in the request scope.